# Java Tomcat LDAP authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap, tomcat6, openldap

Since I'm running Java with Tomcat6 as servlet container I found it appropriate to use the [Tomcat JNDIRealm feature](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm) so that LDAP users can log into my site without any additional efforts. The LDAP server I'm using is [OpenLDAP on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer).

On top of this I have the login page using [form-based authentication](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html) over an [https connection](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-up-ssl-on-tomcat.html).

I found two very good examples of authentication users via LDAP, [here](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/WebContainerAuthenticationViaLDAP) and [here](http://blog.mc-thias.org/?title=tomcat_ldap_authentication&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), that both achieve what I feel I almost achieved. Why *almost* achieved?

When I attempt to login with the wrong credentials I'm appropriately sent to the `<form-error-page>`, `login-failed.html` in my case.

When my credentials are good and I authenticate successfully I start getting a **403 for all urls** in the site. And I cannot remove the 403 error (not even for the login page!) unless I restart Tomcat.

I suspect the reason is because I don't have `roles` in the realm or other config files set up correctly. For the sake of brevity I put the relevant config files excerpts on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/):

- [Realm in Tomcat `server.xml`](http://pastebin.com/35nNzSaS)
- [Relevant `tomcat-users.xml` part](http://pastebin.com/0MYGitp8)
- [Relevant `web.xml` part](http://pastebin.com/1h6W197b)
- [Basic LDAP structure](http://pastebin.com/rQqxqtsm), dashes indicate tree structure

Note that Tomcat-based auth works perfectly since the role is easily attached to the user in the `tomcat-users.xml`. Therefore I believe it's a problem in getting the role for an authenticated user from LDAP once it has been successfully been authenticated.

**TL/DR**

I have a config issue in connecting Tomcat to LDAP auth. User data fetched properly, but not the user's role. LDAP log messages available on request ;)

**UPDATE**: I pasted the LDAP data [here](http://pastebin.com/s6UckuSY).

Comment: do you have a group cn=site-users,ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com and users in that group?

Comment: please also provide some more information about your ldap stracture

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Basic LDAP structure [here](http://pastebin.com/rQqxqtsm). Hence I have `cn=site-users,ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com`. Note that `site-users` has a number of `member` attributes pointing to the users.

Comment: something else is missing from the puzzle... just cant figure out what. As i see your code it should be working

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Refer to my last comment to user EJP below. Thanks for your help, will let you know.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I still can't figure it out, so I pasted the LDAP [here](http://pastebin.com/s6UckuSY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Your LDAP roles aren't being found by the JNDIRealm. You need to test your role search string outside Tomcat to ensure it yields what you think it should yield. As you haven't provided any LDAP details it isn't possible to comment further.

Putting a security-permission on the entire site with /* is a mistake. You need to exclude the login page and probably also the front page and the forgot-password page, maybe more, from requiring a role.

Comment: LDAP details [here](http://pastebin.com/rQqxqtsm). Note that `site-users` has a number of `member` attributes pointing to the users.

Comment: @Josvic 'site-users' doesn't have any 'member' attributes at all that I can see. You seem to have 'uid' in the LDAP groups, but you are telling LDAP to search on 'member'.

Comment: I have a number of users with `uid` under `objectClass` organizational unit `people`. They are *members* of the `groupOfNames`  objectClass `site-users`. A problem with that? So the user should be authenticated. But the user not matched for role `site-users`.

Comment: @JosvicZammit The problem is that I still don't know what's in a 'member' attribute, as you haven't confided it. To work with that search string, it would need to be a complete DN. The user *is* authenticated, he just isn't being *authorized.*

Comment: Exactly. I need write access to change it; I can't modify it right now. But will let you know, as I believe the address of the `member` attribute is incorrect. Will mark your answer as correct if that is the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The change attempted didn't work out. What do you mean by *complete DN* above? I pasted the LDAP data [here](http://pastebin.com/s6UckuSY).

Comment: @JosvicZammit You have the complete DN in the `member` attribute. I would investigate whether the binddn and password are correct. If possible investigate the LDAP logs for bind failures.