# LDAP authentication for Tomcat - 403 error

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap

I want to secure my Tomcat server using LDAP.

Firstly, I try it against an online LDAP test server, that its details exist in http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ .

My tomcat server redirects the all requests from port 8080 to port 8433, then it ask for username and password, then (when I enter the correct data) returns an 403 error-page.

What is the problem?

the relevant sections from server.xml:

```
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="10"
                            connectionURL="ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389"
                            alternateURL="ldaps://ldap.forumsys.com:636"
                            userBase="dc=example,dc=com"
                            userSearch="(uid={0})"
                            userSubtree="true"
                            userRoleName="l"
                            connectionName="cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
                            connectionPassword="password"
            /> 
  </Realm>
```

the relevant section from web.xml:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>main.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Authenticated area</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/main.html</url-pattern>
           <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
           <http-method>PUT</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>

       <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
           <role-name>Admin</role-name>
           <role-name>Authenticated</role-name>
           <role-name>mathematicians</role-name>
           <role-name>gauss</role-name>
           <role-name>galieleo</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>

   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
       <description>
           This logical role includes all authenticated users
       </description>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
       <role-name>site-users</role-name>
       <role-name>Authenticated</role-name>
       <role-name>mathematicians</role-name>
       <role-name>gauss</role-name>
       <role-name>galieleo</role-name>
   </security-role>  
</web-app>
```

the relevant section from tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
  <role rolename="mathematicians"/>
  <role rolename="site-users"/>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <user username="gauss" roles="site-users,user,tomcat" />
</tomcat-users>
```

I use username "gauss" and password "password"

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198263/java-tomcat-ldap-authentication) helps...

Comment: I see that thread before I wrote my question. But I didn't find there any response that can help me.

Comment: If you are using LDAP authentication, then your `tomcat-users.xml` file is completely irrelevant.

Comment: What LDAP search string can you use to successfully pull the roles for an arbitrary user e.g. "gauss"? Is the user-role name really `l`?

Comment: I wrote all details. I see in Wireshark a good response from the Ldap server

Answer (score 0):

What is the userRoleName="l" This should be l=locale attribute on the user entries in LDAP and the values MUST be ONE of

```
<role-name>tomcat</role-name>
<role-name>site-users</role-name>
<role-name>Authenticated</role-name>
<role-name>mathematicians</role-name>
<role-name>gauss</role-name>
<role-name>galieleo</role-name>
```

If you want ANY authenticated user make it just:

```
<role-name>*</role-name>
```

[Try looking here for more information.](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Security-constraint)